# Mann-Kendall test identify positive or negative trend R

Tags: r, time-series, trend

Do not know if with the R function `MannKendall(x)` (package ‘Kendall’) I can determine whether my data follows a monotonic increase or derease? I know that a low p-value implies that the data follows a monotonic trend but can I determine somehow with the outputs of this function the direction of the increase? Is there any other function/library in R that performs a Mann-Kendall trend test which an provide me that information?

Thank you in advane!